# construct object function with array parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In Javascript, if I want to construct a object which can be used into polymorphism and inheritance, I would like to code like this:

```
function clicked(label,name,value){
    this.label=label;
    this.name=name;
    this.value=value;
}
```

When I want to create new object, I can use following methods:

```
var clicked1= new clicked("a","b","c");
var clicked2= new clicked("d","e","f");
clicked1.label="h";
```

**But here I want to change some parameter into array. How can I do.
for example, Change every label keys into label[ ], thus I can use later:**

```
clicked1.label.push("xxx");
```

Comment: just.... some parameter are type of array instead of just string, I want to know how to change my code for that...

Comment: So just use an array instead of a string.  What did you try writing? What don't you understand?

Comment: oh my god = =! Can I just use like: var clicked1= new clicked([],[],[]); ?  I think I didn't understand this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are very simple in Javascript:

```
var clickedArray = new clicked([], "b", "c"); 
// label is an array in this instance of your object
clicked1.label.push("xxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getters/setters:

```
function clicked(lbl,name,value){
    var label=lbl;
    this.name=name;
    this.value=value;
    this.getLabel = function(){
        return label;
    };

    this.setLabel = function(lbl){
        label = lbl;
    };
}
```